# Wordpress custom text meta box

Tags: wordpress

So I need to display some basic text below the WP editor, nothing more nothing less. I only found a lot of stuff that's confusing to me(haven't worked with WP in ages). Can anybody point me to a tutorial about a basic meta box or drop the code below.

No I don't want to use any kind of plugin :)

Comment: But you're a regular [so] user, so you should know that recommendation questions and *gimme teh codez* are off-topic, no?

Answer (score 0):

Add a meta box with `add_meta_box` via the Codex.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

```
<?php
   add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $post_type, $context,
         $priority, $callback_args );
?>
```

Check the example on the codex as it shows you saving, outputting the data.